# How obsolete is the word "overmorrow"?

Tags: early-modern-english

I stumbled over the word [overmorrow](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overmorrow) and wanted to know whether it is in use.

So I used [Googles Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overmorrow&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and wondered why it has not found a single reference.

Was *overmorrow* only used one time in the bible?

Comment: Interesting: In German there's "übermorgen" which literally translates to "overmorrow" and means "the day after tomorrow".

Comment: @JoachimSauer, other languages have the it (and use it), too (see the wiktionary link http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overmorrow). What is really interesting is that English had it, but lost it.

Comment: I am so definitely adding this word to my vocabulary.

Comment: My first langauge is Afrikaans (South Africa - Dutch settlers) and we very commonly use the word "oormôre" which translated literally means over & morrow and also has exactly the same meaning - the day after tomorrow, therefore there should be no reason why it should not be very commonly used - especially in the place of "The day after tomorrow..." Johan du Plessis

Comment: In dutch it's called "overmorgen" and it is in common use!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's a bit strange - searching the google books directly for "overmorrow" gives 16 results, see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=over%20morrow&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22overmorrow%22&pbx=1&oq=%22overmorrow%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3251l4426l2l4682l2l2l0l0l0l0l248l248l2-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=aff5e50bd73009ef&biw=1199&bih=795).

The measure of obsoleteness (and strangeness) is that fact that it is listed in 1913 Webster, but not in 1828 Webster. Also note that many dictionaries do not list it at all (for comparison use the results on onelook, [here](http://www.onelook.com/?w=overmorrow&ls=a))

I would say that it is long obsolete word that was never common.

Comment: First [OED citation](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/134854) is from 1535. Its etymology says ‘probably after German *übermorgen’.* It is marked as *obs. rare*.

Comment: @tchrist Presently, overmorrow or 'lendemain'(après-demain) is regularly used in French but the etymology is "From Middle English overmorwe, a compound of over + morwe (“morrow”). Compare Dutch overmorgen, German übermorgen, Swedish övermorgon, Danish overmorgen, Norwegian overmorgen." https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overmorrow#Etymology