# Is there a one-word English term for the day after tomorrow?

Tags: terminology, time, is-it-a-word, dates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How obsolete is the word “overmorrow”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45412/how-obsolete-is-the-word-overmorrow)

Is there a one-word English term for the day after tomorrow? Perhaps a term that has fallen out of modern English usage.

One that would complete the sequence of: today, tomorrow, ...

Comment: Related: [How obsolete is the word “overmorrow”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45412/how-obsolete-is-the-word-overmorrow)

Comment: @aedia: I think it's a bit more than "related". It's the answer, and then some.

Comment: The day after tomorrow is "Friday"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.

There may have been one, or more, and there may still be dialectal variants around here and there. But there's no general word; instead there's a fixed phrase, which you used: *the day after tomorrow*.

Germanic languages can use the word for *morning* to refer to the next daybreak. In German *Morgen* **still** means both *morning* and *tomorrow*; in English *morrow*, a variant of *morning*,  came to be used in the latter sense. The *to-* is probably a fossilized definite article.

In German, with its transparent morphology, there **is** a word *Übermorgen* that means *the day after tomorrow*, but English is morphologically naked. If there **were** such a word, it would be *overmorrow*.

Comment: Awesome answers. Funny enough - overmorrow will work for what I need, but good to know I shouldn't use as if I'm speaking correct English. Thanks.

Comment: If enough of us start using overmorrow, it will become proper English soon. Like 'selfie'.

Comment: Maybe. But there are a lot of occasions for saying _selfie_. How often do people have to refer to the day after tomorrow? Two days before every holiday or air flight, maybe. But go ahead, that's how it's done, all right.

Comment: Fun fact: _morning_ and _tomorrow_ share a common descriptor also in Polish (so not a Germanic language): the standard word for "morning" is _rano/ranek_, but the old-fashioned _jutrzenka_ ("morning"/"dawn") is decidedly related to _jutro_ ("tomorrow").
The same seems to happen in Romance languages... I would guess that _demain_ ("tomorrow") used to be _de matin_ ("in the [upcoming] morning"). -- (Mind you: _overmorrow_ = _pojutrze_ in Polish, literally "after tomorrow" - which is more sensible than days that are "over"/"under" other days... But overmorrow should be reintroduced regardless.)