# Can you give me other one-word time terminologies aside from fortnight and yestreen?

Tags: word-usage

What are other time terminologies that can be used in just only 1 word? For example,
**today**- for this day or at the present time
**tomorrow**- means the day after today
**yesterday**- the day before today
**week**- means 7 days
**fortnight**- means two weeks

And i just recently know that ***yestreen***, a chiefly Scottish word means *last night*.

Comment: Month, year, decade, century, millennium.  And, of course, second, minute, hour, and day.

Comment: Some can be found at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110074/a-more-succinct-expression-for-the-day-before-yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Tomorn" is still heard in the more rural parts of my native Shropshire, although mostly by an older gneration. It is taken to mean, specifically, tomorrow *morning* (and usually very early at that), and is not a substitute for "tomorrow".

The OED has it listed as being near obsolete in literary English by 1500, revived in the mid-19th Century for poetic purposes, but I can assure you that it is alive--- if not all that well--- in the every--day speech of many Salopians.

Comment: Swell. Thanks, These words I am looking for. Not the one @Hugh is referring to. Those examples he gave are so common.

Answer (score 0):

*Also*  **Time** described in relation to another time.

**Anniversary** and **birthday**.
An **octave** is the day which occurs one week later,
A **lunaversary** occurs one month later.
A **Jubilee** which is usually now 25yrs.
The **eve** of a day is the day before.

*Also* the four **[Seasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Season)**, or the Four Quarters with their Quarter Days:

**Spring, Summer, Autumn, Winter.**
An **Equinox** is the day when day is as long as night.
A **Solstice** is the day when "the Sun stands still" before the Earth tilts back again.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the comment by Hot Licks
**Semester** can be used for a six month period:

> 1. either of the two usually 18-week periods of instruction into which an academic year is often divided
> 2. a period of six months

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/semester