# Is there a word meaning the day after tommorow?

Tags: single-word-requests

My question comes from this picture :D[image: picture]

For example in my native language, russian, there is a word.

> Завтра - tomorrow
>
> Послезавтра - "after-tomorrow"

So my question, is that correct to say "aftertomorrow" to point at the day after tomorrow?

Comment: Apparently, "overmorrow", although it's not common and may be obsolete: [How obsolete is the word “overmorrow”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45412/how-obsolete-is-the-word-overmorrow)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a one-word English term for the day after tomorrow?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51675/is-there-a-one-word-english-term-for-the-day-after-tomorrow)