# Difference between "day after tomorrow" and "day after next"

Tags: terminology

According to [the internet's wisdom](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the%20day%20after%20next), the term "*day after next*" means a day that might never come - basically **some** day in the future, if any at all.

However, in *Covert Affairs* (S04E14) they seem to use that term to denote the day after tomorrow. Can the former be used as the latter as well? Is that a cultural thing?

Comment: _Day after next_ is short for _day after tomorrow_ when referring to the present day; however, it can be back- or foreshifted to refer to any day, like _next day_.

Comment: The internet (as commonly happens) is wrong. Both "the day after tomorrow" and "the day after next" *literally* mean two days from today. I have seen both used *metaphorically* for ***some*** day in the future. The only distinction between them is that one is somewhat more likely to be used metaphorically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion is in the present usage but 'day after next 'exists as in plenty of languages: overmorrow, lendemain, après-demain, (Middle English) overmorwe, overmorgen, übermorgen, övermorgon,  overmorgen, overmorgen...([How obsolete is the word "overmorrow"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45412/how-obsolete-is-the-word-overmorrow)).

As for the culture, science fiction words and definitions are defined by the author, and sometimes the audience.  Notably, a mother's usage of "day after next" is likely defined as 'a day that may never come'

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain what's improvable in this reply?