# Is there a popular expression in english to say "pasadomañana" as in spanish?

Tags: expressions, terminology, translation

There is in spanish a word **"pasadomañana"** to refer to the day after tomorrow, I wonder if maybe there is an popular/informal way to mean the same without say the day after tomorrow

Comment: I'm not aware of any - just say "the day after tomorrow".

Comment: There is the word _overmorrow_, but that word is, as covered in [How obsolete is the word _overmorrow_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45412/how-obsolete-is-the-word-overmorrow), quite archaic and not used in normal conversation. I am not aware of any commonly used word either; we just say ‘the day after tomorrow’.

Comment: Both Jeff and Janus are correct. One implication of Janus’ point I’ll call our explicitly: if you say *overmorrow*, no one will know what you mean. Though of course context solves all problems.....

Comment: From what I've seen pasado mañana is two words.

Comment: You have the Italian *dopodomani* if you like .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes absolutely! One of the most popular expressions to refer to the day after tomorrow is "in two days", an expression slightly shorter than "pasadomañana". Or something similar, depending on the context.

(In fact, it's so common that any answer that dares suggest it might seem condescending, but I'll try my best.)

This expression can be used in pretty much any type of writing: formal, informal, headlines, txtspk, spoken, written, period-specific, etc.

(This is not something true for "overmorrow", a now-obsolete word which appears neither in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) nor [Google N-Grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overmorrow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=). It was never popular, since the OED marks it as "obsolete rare", so if you use this word you risk clarity.)

When used in informal writing, the number isn't always written out: "in 2 days". More rarely, in extremely informal writing, sometimes the space after 2 is removed. In places where hashtags are common, you can sometimes see things written as a hashtag, although this is also pretty rare: "in #2days".

Although there are many false positives, you can find more examples on Twitter ([in two days](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22in%20two%20days%22&src=typd), [in 2 days](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22in%202%20days%22&src=typd), [in 2days](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22in%202days%22&src=typd), [in #2days](https://twitter.com/search?q=in%20%232days&src=typd)).

There is also an adjective form, seen for example on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=3043211):

> FREE **Two-Day** Shipping through Amazon Prime

Comment: Hm...for whatever reason I never realized that 'in two days' meant 'the day after tomorrow'. Two days seems so far off to me, but tomorrow plus one so much closer.

Comment: It also brings into question which day was the first day. Does the counting start now, or tomorrow? While I'd agree with the standard timing mentioned above, I only had to go as far as my brother to find someone who counts it differently. Perhaps this is why we don't say it that way, or alternatively there is different understanding because we don't have any practice with it since we just say the other thing.

Answer (score 0):

In recent years, casual conversation has begun using "sleeps" to describe future days.

> Just **two sleeps** until I get my new Elmo slippers!

See this [Twitter search](https://twitter.com/search?q=two%20sleeps) about "two sleeps".

Alternatively, as shown by [Tony's character in Seinfeld](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnSwz-9LLc4), you could just use the Spanish (pasadomañana, in this case) to add flavour to what you're saying.

Comment: As an American, I have never heard that particular use of "sleeps". In my area at least, most people would probably understand what you mean, but you'd get some pretty weird looks and maybe some questions about the weird usage of sleeps. This might be regional though, so it probably depends on where you're from as to whether this is common or not.

Comment: Also an American, and I have heard 'sleeps' but only by parents of small children, and it doesn't translate directly to days, because you have to account for naps.

Answer (score -1):

Not really an expression, but how about this one: [overmorrow](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overmorrow)?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45412/how-obsolete-is-the-word-overmorrow

Comment: The question is asking for a popular or informal expression – this is very much neither. It’s so archaic and obsolete, in fact, that many dictionaries no longer even have it.