# Is there a word for "the day after overmorrow" and "the day before ereyesterday"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, vocabulary

I know *overmorrow (the day after tomorrow)* and *ereyesterday (the day before yesterday)* themselves are obsolete alike. I would like to know whether English has ever had  words for one day farther than that, I mean "the day after overmorrow" and "the day before ereyesterday".

Comment: Please provide definitions of these words in your question—don't make people have to search to find out what they mean in order to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45412/how-obsolete-is-the-word-overmorrow

Answer (score 6):

There is an historical record of ***third morrow*** meaning the same thing as ***overmorrow***. See OED sense 2b of *morrow*.

**So presumably there is no reason one could not use "fourth", "fifth" or "sixth" morrow**.

> 2b. the third morrow: the next day but one. the next morrow: the day
>   after. Frequently used adverbially. Now rare (arch. and literary).
>   c1325   in G. L. Brook Harley Lyrics (1968) 57   Hire blisse sprong þe
>   þridde morewe. ▸ a1393   Gower Confessio Amantis (Fairf.) ii. 2713
>   (MED)   Wherof his lord..A seknesse er the thridde morwe Conceived
>   hath of dedly sorwe. a1400  (▸a1325)    Cursor Mundi (Vesp.) 24549
>   (MED)   He hight to rise þe thrid moru. a1450   Generides (Pierpont
>   Morgan) (1865) 5621   On the thrid morow Bellins, the king, Rose erlie
>   or the day gan spring. a1522   G. Douglas tr. Virgil Æneid (1957) iii.
>   ii. 97   Our navy sall, with help of Jupiter, The thrid morow be at
>   the cost of Crete. 1533   J. Bellenden tr. Livy Hist. Rome (1901) I.
>   65   The nixt morow he wald mak ane sacrifice lustrale als sone as
>   licht apperit. a1586   Sir P. Sidney Arcadia (1590) ii. 162   He would
>   the third morrow after, before the walles of the towne strike off
>   Antiphilus head. a1645   W. Browne tr. M. Le Roy Hist. Polexander
>   (1647) i. iii. 65   The Assembly..thought it fit to resolve of nothing
>   that day, but that they should meet againe the next morrow to conclude
>   all things. a1722   J. Lauder Hist. Notices Sc. Affairs (1848) II. 651
>   The Privy Counsell ordained the Criminal Court to sit on him the nixt
>   morrow. 1893   A. Webster Portraits 20   The next morrow they will
>   feel their ease And sigh with sleek content, or laugh elate. 1906   C.
>   M. Doughty Dawn in Brit. I. iii. 157   They, with Arunt, Will the
>   third morrow march, in aid, towards Clusium.

Comment: Interesting! *Morrow* means morning. From Etymonline: "tomorrow (adv.)

mid-13c., to morewe, from Old English to morgenne "on (the) morrow," from to "at, on" (see to) + morgenne, dative of morgen"morning" (see morn, also morrow). As a noun from late 14c. Written as two words until 16c., then as to-morrow until early 20c.

"