# Can obsolete words be reintroduced?

Tags: history, historical-change

I personally really like to use the word [overmorrow](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overmorrow). It is convenient to use, and much shorter compared to the traditionally used `the day after tomorrow`.

However, according to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45412/how-obsolete-is-the-word-overmorrow) the word has become obsolete in the dictionary after 1913. And is not used in modern English language.

My question is: how would one, hypothetically speaking, go about reintroducing words that have become obsolete? Are there examples of words that had become obsolete and have been reintroduced? If so, how did this happen?

Comment: Personally, I prefer “threemorrow” ;). More seriously, there is no standard, reliable, or predicable process to effect language change. There is no central authority to appeal to, now law to amend … language is just the broad consensus of millions of people at any given time or place. To get “overmorrow” reintroduced, you have to convince a whole lot of people to use it. Maybe you can write a book or movie to play that gets super popular and uses the word at a very dramatic point, or by a character everyone loves… that is, “meme” it into existence. But I wouldn’t hold my breath.

Comment: 'bespoke' was obsolete, then people started using it again [(past 20 years)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bespoke&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3). Whether obsolete or made up totally new, the way to do it is 1) be a writer for a major publication (NYT, etc) 2) be clever and hit a cultural touchpoint 3) be lucky

Comment: You can write in code if you want to. But if you're at all bothered that others will think you ridiculous, crazy or pretentious, you'll avoid using such obsolete words (I dodged 'obsolescences' there) except perhaps in very carefully engineered contexts.

Comment: Compare [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/what-are-the-criteria-to-adopt-new-words-into-english) about getting new words known and used.

Comment: According to "English Words Re-Introduction Law" of 1590, Passed by the World-Wide English Lawyers Association, trying to [[or even thinking about trying to]] re-introduce absolutely obsolete words is a Punishable offense. Expect the Spanish Inquisition to make a visit shortly !

Comment: @Mitch Maybe the route these days is to find an "influencer" and get them to use the word.